# Reading a long comma separated line to a column in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a very long comma separated string that I want to read as a column vector in R. 
I tried to read it as a table, wondering if I could just transpose that, but reading into table takes forever.

```
col = read.table("filename.csv", sep = ",", header=FALSE)
colT = t(col)
```

The string is huge and has 2.7M entries separated by commas. Therefore it cannot be handled in a text editor and trying to replace ',' by '\n' was futile. Is there a way I can do that in R?

Comment: `?scan` is the guts of `read.table` and will probably be considerably quicker too.

Comment: Have you tried `read_csv` in `readr` package?

Comment: No I haven't. I am trying

Comment: You can use GNU `tr` (translate) to quickly replace "," with "\n": `cat filename.csv | tr ',' '\n' > filename_newline.csv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?scan` will be quite quick for this sort of thing.

```
tmp <- paste(paste0(letters,1:2.7e6),collapse=",")
system.time(scan(text=tmp, what=character(1), sep=","))
#Read 2700000 items
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.15    0.00    1.16
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread("filename.csv", header=FALSE)

tmp <- paste(paste0(letters,1:2.7e6),collapse="\n")
system.time(fread(tmp, header=FALSE))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.87    0.00    0.88
```

If the OP's data have `,` and not `\n`, we can use `gsub` as @thelatemail mentioned

```
fread(gsub(",","\n",tmp),header=FALSE)
```

Comment: Won't you need something like `fread(gsub(",","\n",tmp),header=FALSE)` as OP does not have line-breaks in their data?